# How to See Git Branch in Visual Studio Commit Details?

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

When I look at git commit details in visual studio 2019, it doesn't show the branch it was committed to.  How can I easily find this out?  thanks.

[image]

Comment: Commits aren't made to branches. Commits have parents and children. Branches and tags are pointers to specific commits.

Comment: Hi, Dan, how about John's answer? Does his answer could help you solve the puzzle?  If yes, you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works. If you are still facing some issues please leave a comment so we can still help you .

Comment: ok yes I accepted his answer, it would be nice if that was included in VS when we look at commit detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Daniel in the comments, git branches are simply pointers to commits. You can find out which branches contain the commit using the following command

```
git branch --contains <hash>
```